# Order of #includes to avoid linking errors

Tags: c++, include

Sometimes in C++ the order of the includes matters. That is the case of openGL using :

**1.- Right way:**

```
#include <windows.h>                // Header File For Windows
#include <gl\glu.h>                 // Header File For The GLu32 Library
```

**2.- Wrong way:**

```
#include <gl\glu.h>                 // Header File For The GLu32 Library
#include <windows.h>                // Header File For Windows
```

> Does this happen just for some specific headers or is it kind of a
>   random problem difficult to prevent a priori?

If that is the case:

> How can I know the right order of the includes?

Comment: This has nothing to do with _linking_, only compiling.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Not necessarily.  Macros in one may change function prototypes in the other, causing unresolved externals later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Just some specific headers.  Some might call it a design flaw.
2. You can't.  Look at the error messages you get and sort them out carefully.  On windows, putting windows.h first is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The order does not matter for C++ Standard Library includes.
For other libraries it should not usually matter (unless they specifically say so).
For specific platforms, it may matter and it is usually specified clearly when it does.

For ex:

On Windows `#include <windows.h>` comes before all the other includes.

Also,
`#include <stdafx.h>`
which is a MSVC++ specific header needs to be included before everything else if you're using precompiled headers.

Comment: `stdafx.h` is Visual Studio wizard-generated nonsense.  If you're going to use a precompiled header, call it `precompiled.h` or `common.h` or something sensible.  And angle brackets should not be used with a project-local header such as `stdafx.h`.

Answer (score 2):

For windows you need the `#include <windows.h>` first.

Then in the header files avoid `#include` - prefer forward declarations instead.

Save less compilation when you just change one header file.

Answer (score 2):

At one time, a fair number of well-known C programmers advised that no header should include any other header -- it should be up to the user to include the correct headers in the correct order to make things work. This worked (and continues to work) pretty well for small projects that don't involve too many headers.

For larger projects, however, keeping track of all the header dependencies can/does become substantially more difficult, to the point that it's nearly unmanageable in many modern code bases. Most modern headers themselves include any other headers upon which they depend.

Unfortunately, that means we frequently end up with a rather confusing mixture of the two. There's not much you can do beyond just dealing with it when it arises, by finding what headers you need to include and in what order.